# Minimise Mean square error(MMSE) proof procedure

Tags: probability, optimization, mean-square-error

I am awkard to understand the basic things so 
I have suffered from the procedure of proving the minimize the mean square error.

the mean square error is

$$ E[(X-g(Y))^{2}]=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}E[(X-g(Y))^2|Y=y]f_y(y)dy $$

and I understand the $E[(X-g(Y))^2|Y=y] \ge 0 $ and $f_y(y) \ge 0$

After the only $g(y)$ is chosen to be minimized the inner
expectation $E[(X-g(Y))^2|Y=y]$

I don't understand to consider only this formula to find $g(y)$

So I could not understand the why $f_y(y)$ is disappeared and

it only cares just case  $ E[(X-g(Y))^2|Y=y] $

( I think that it seems to be considered about $ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty}E[(X-g(Y))^2|Y=y] $  if $f_y(y) $ is disappeared )

Thank you very much in advance.
Welcome to think for hint and advice :)

Comment: why is that $g(x) = E[(X-g(Y))^2 \mid Y=y]$? There is no $x$ at the rhs.

Comment: shouldn't the optimal $g$ be given by $g(y) = E[X \mid Y = y]$?

Comment: @user251257 should reedit :) Thank you for your comments!